# How to add a progress bar to function with no necessary iterations?

Tags: r, progress-bar, data.table

I am rephrasing a previous question I asked a few days ago. I would edit the other question but this revision is different enough to stand alone.

How can I add a progress bar to a function that has no -- in my current understanding -- necessary iterations. My function modifies large data.table (>2,500,000 observations) with some assignments and aggregation. Using `as.POSIXct` on five million ambiguous times takes a minute no matter what, so, I would like a progress indicator:

```
clean_tables <- function(x) {

      headers <- c("TIMESTAMP","RECORD","CO2","H2O","LI7000Pres","Solenoid","AvgCO2In","AVGH2OIn",
                   "AvgCO2Out","AvgH2OOut","QIn_Avg","AirTempIN","AirTempOUT","Spare","DeltaT",
                   "DeltaCO2","DRIVEmv","FanDrive","HWA","Vel","Flow","QOut_Avg","QLine_Avg","AvgDT",
                   "IRTC_Avg","SoilTemp","BenchTemp","CO2error","CO2mvinc","CO2mvdrive")

      pb <- txtProgressBar(style = 3)
      setTxtProgressBar(pb, length(x))
      colnames(x) <- headers
      x <- unique(x)
      x <<- x[order(RECORD)]
      x[, TIMESTAMP := as.POSIXct(TIMESTAMP, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")]
      x_1_minute <<- x[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = TIMESTAMP]
      x_15_minute <<- data.table(aggregate.ts(x_1_minute, 1/15, mean))
      x_15_minute[, TIMESTAMP := as.POSIXct(TIMESTAMP, origin = '1970-01-01')]
    }


clean_tables(big_table)
```

When I run the function the progress bar will show only 0% because there are no iterations and subsequent updates to the progress bar. If I add progress bars to the `lapply` loops-- or create extra loops just for that sake-- it is probably less efficient. So, one indicator for the entire function is my goal (that actually updates). Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: hello there is a package for progress bar in apply  here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbapply/

Comment: @s.brunel that requires loops - lapply, which OP wants to avoid.

Comment: maybe you can use `fastPOSIXct` from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fasttime/  if it's fast enough you won't need a progress bar

Comment: Create 100 subset of yourdatabase before using `as.POSIXct`, loop on the 100 subset, use `as.POSIXct` inside de loop, you might loose some second, but you would have your progress bar

Comment: try the `anytime` package. it's super-fast and shld handle those formats.

Comment: @timat Thank you. My reluctance to break up the data is that it will cause partial aggregations for the 1 minute data.table, right? I would then need to put it back together and aggregate once more to create the 1 minute data.table.

Comment: @hrbrmster I just used the anytime package on one of my big data.table (6,000,000 observations) and it still takes enough time to warrant an indication of progress.

Comment: I should mention that @Roland as advised me to forget the progress bar and focus on performance in my similar (but different enough) question. He is right, I'm sure. Knowing progress of the overall function is not necessary but certainly useful. Also when I hand this script to others they will be happy to that know it is working and not hung somewhere.

Comment: @W.Dodge my idea was to break the data only for the `as.POSIXct` fonction, then collapse then again before the agreggate, then break it again for the second `as.POSIXct`... It might add few second in the process though but if you're process is more than 1 minute..also you can just show as information that it would take 1 or 2 minutes as an infomartion, without progress bar

Comment: @timat I'm going to use your idea of simply printing message `Aggregation may take a minute or two` to inform user.